# Assist a Beginner in Solving An Easy JS Indexing Question

Tags: javascript

Here is the problem:

> Write a function, *stringIndexOf*, which accepts two strings: the first is a word and the second is a single character.

> The function should return the first index in the word at which the character exists or -1 if the character is not found. Do not use the built in String.indexOf() function.

What is really confusing me is that it says not to use the built in string.indexOf() function. I cannot figure out how to solve this without it...

Here are some of the solutions I have come up with using the .indexOf() method (I know that the first two are redundant and effectively the same as the 3rd - but I wanted to try exhausting the concepts I am familiar with). Would be grateful if someone could give me an alternate solution using JS - and explain it like I'm a baby.

```html
// 1st Solution using an If... Else statement

function stringIndexOf(string, character) {
     if (string.includes(character)) {
         console.log(string.indexOf(character));
     } else { console.log('-1'); }
}


// 2nd solution using a For... Of loop
 
 function stringIndexOf(string, character) {
     for (let index of character) {
         console.log(string.indexOf(character));
     }
}

// 3rd Solution using a simple indexOf
 
 function stringIndexOf(string, character) {
     console.log(string.indexOf(character));
}
```

This problem should be easy as it is part of a pre-bootcamp course I am taking - am i maybe misreading what the question means by not using the built in function? Is there any particular reason why excluding the use of indexOf() would be preferable in this situation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In real life `indexOf` would of course be preferable. The point of the assignment is to learn the basic operations that functions like `indexOf()` use.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```js
/*The function should return the first index in the word at which the character exists or -1 if the character is not found. Do not use the built in String.indexOf() function.*/

function stringIndexOf(str, letter) {
  if (str.length && letter.length === 1) {
    const lettersArray = str.split('');

    for (let i = 0; i < lettersArray.length; i++) {
      if (lettersArray[i] === letter) {
        return i;
      }
    }
  }

  return -1;
}

console.log(stringIndexOf("dog", "g"));
```